# Received close_notify during handshake

Tags: ssl

I've configured SSL(HTTPS) on all my 18 servers. All 18 servers communicate with each other using SSL. Everything was working fine. Suddenly I got this error:

> "Received close_notify during handshake"
>
> LOG ::@2011-06-03 03:36:17.372 [Log.class]
> ![LoadBalancer][com.somename.servlet][RequestServlet][callServlet] ==>
> [spnlapp01390.europe.intranet:8443/TCServer/TCHealthCheck] -> Reason :
> Received close_notify during handshake #3996073076

The strange thing is after application restart, its working fine. I've no idea about this cause. In which scenario this can happen? Is this because of a network issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The close_notify is message sent by SSL stack to indicate termination of the connection. Without some more data to look at such as network trace, it is very hard (if at all possible) to have a definite reason why this has happened.

Answer (score 2):

We found the same issue with our server where our servers are going too busy with condition to serve 100 connections per second. It works fine with restarting server but with longevity situations again issue repeats. And you may see this very frequently where nodes (server and client) are located in network too far to reach.

We did hardware upgrades and server configuration tuning like increasing the open files (linux) value, allowing maximum possible ports to use, increasing maximum threads and connections allowed in web server. Setting the proper SO and Connection time outs and then managing the client resources (connections) reusing and proper client shutdowns brought good control. Reducing the other pings to server over HTTP/HTTPS communications like heartbeat, user accesses to front end applications and some other cache updating clients made the scene better.

Still we have same issue in case of less performing machines and windows 7 environment machines.

Comment: We'll have to agree on one point that, we'll also have to look into our application for this issue.
Whatever you have mentioned & configuration did on your server is absolutely correct.
But if we'll think from bit different angle, we should have some mechanism on server side to control client requests at one time.

Comment: For e.g. we can keep one entry point on server which Blocks client request for certain amount of time, if server is processing (say 100) requests concurrently at a time.
So, once any one of the 100 processes frees, server can accept next request.
So, something on these lines we can build one entry point on server.