# Github unable to access... gnutls_handshake() failed:Close notify

Tags: git, github, raspberry-pi, git-clone, gnutls

When attempting to git clone any repository I get this error

```
fatal: unable to access <repo url>: gnutls_handshake() failed: Close notify
```

Just incase it helps I am on a Raspberry Pi Zero.

Git version: 2.1.4

libgnutls-deb0 version 3.3.8-6+deb9 architecture armhf

libgnutls-open version 3.3.8-6+deb9 architecture armhf

Comment: And yes I do have good connection

Comment: What version of Git and what version of GnuTLS are you using?

Comment: 'git version' reports 'git version 2.1.4' and attempting to update with 'sudo apt-get update git' says it is the latest version already.

Comment: Not sure how to check gnutls version.

Comment: EDIT: On my second comment, I meant 'sudo apt-get install git'

Comment: You can find the version of GnuTLS by doing `dpkg -l libgnutls*`.

Comment: libgnutls-deb0 and libgnutls-open both report '3.3.8-6+deb8' with the 'armhf; architecture

Comment: hm, might put a bounty on this.

Comment: You haven't said, but I assume from the tags you're attempting to connect to GitHub. Are you on a public Wi-Fi network on in a situation with a proxy, like a corporate environment? This message means the server said it didn't want to complete the encrypted connection, so either GitHub hung up (usually because the protocol is too old, which is not the case here) or someone in the middle did.

Comment: No, i am at home. No proxies or anything like that, just a normal router. I can download github repos from the actual website itself, but thats not an option if trying to install something from a script that automatically tries to clone github repos (a lot of them too in this case.)

Comment: Related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289948/received-close-notify-during-handshake

Comment: Problem is, everyone else seems to be able to connect. Also I get this consistently. At least its not completely unheard of though.

Comment: Did you changed anything in SSL Certificate?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/186847/error-gnutls-handshake-failed-when-connecting-to-https-servers
Use above link see the error details and step to solve

Comment: Different issue and wont work anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> git config --global http.sslVerify false

to disable verification it lets you clone but it's not the best solution you should check server configuration.

Hope it helps

Comment: That isn't going to work in this case, because it's the server notifying the client that it's closing the connection, not the client refusing to continue the negotiation because the certificate is invalid.